# How to select Random record in Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure

What is the efficient way to select random record out of out put list in Azure table? Following code return always same record. Whats the reason for that?

```
T entity = new T();

TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>();

var tableSet = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();

if (tableSet.Count >= 1)
{
    return tableSet.First();
}

return null;
```

Comment: There is no exactly efficient way to get a random value from Table Storage. This kind of storage works like a dictionary, it returns the result faster when providing the key. As such, Table Storage works, you should provide a PartitionKey and a RowKey to return the result in the most efficient way. These are called Point queries. Other queries are Range queries (on PK or RK) or Full table scan queries which are very bad for performance regarding the amount of data stored and the Partitioning strategy followed.

Answer (score 2):

> Following code return always same record. Whats the reason for that?

As you know the records in an Azure Table are sorted alphabetically, first by `PartitionKey` and then by `RowKey` for each `PartitionKey`. Because you didn't specify any query condition, table service will start fetching the data from the top (i.e. 1st Partition). Now you're asking the table storage to return only one record, it will pick the very 1st record in that Partition. This is why you're getting the same record.

If you want to get random result back, you have to specify some query parameter. One such possibility could be to specify a PartitionKey value at random. If the PartitionKey exists in the table, then it would return the 1st record in that Partition.

Comment: Just to add that Range queries are slow especially if you are querying huge tables. Range queries on PartitionKey are better for performance than on RowKeys and of course on table properties (which can essentially lead to full table scan). So if a range query is to be made it should be on PartitionKey instead.

Comment: Completely agree with you.

Comment: @GauravMantri So to get the random record, if it needs to specify some value for `PartitionKey `, how to select it randomly from the table?

Comment: Since PartitionKey value can be any string value, this is something you need to decide as you know how the PartitionKey values are generated by your code. To give you an example, if we look at diagnostics data stored in WAD** tables, we know that PartitionKey value actually denotes date/time ticks (in UTC) with minute precision. So in this case, you would randomly pick a date/time value, convert that to ticks and use that for querying.

Comment: @GauravMantri In my case this`PartitionKey ` is a GUID which is being generated through the app dynamically e.g. `3bcbb4ae-3283-421f-897a-4354749aa27d `

Comment: I think in this case your best bet would be to do a `Partition Scan` query though I must tell you that it is not efficient as mentioned in the comments above. Just thinking out loud, GUID follows a certain structure (letters a through f and numbers 0 through 9) so you could create 2 random strings and then do a query like `PartitionKey >= first random string && PartitionKey <= second random string`. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri BTW is there a method to access nth record in Azure query result set?

Comment: So a query result set can only return a maximum of 1000 records. You can fetch 1000 records and then pick any record at random using standard LINQ's `Skip(randomRecordNumber).Take(1)` approach. HTH.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for feed back on this question. I arrived at following solution to pickup a random record from the out put list.

```
T entity = new T();

    TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>();

    var tableSet = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    if (tableSet.Count >= 1)
    {
        return tableSet.ElementAt(rnd.Next(1, tableSet.Count));
    }

    return null;
```

Comment: This is going to retrieve all records and perform the random select client side. Yikes.